# BizTalk HL7 2009: HL7 v. 2.6 MSH Error on Timestamp

Tags: biztalk, hl7, biztalk-2009

I’m having trouble getting BizTalk 2009 to accept a HL7 v 2.6 message via the HL7 Accelerator. I’ve used the [HL7 Schema Generation Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=94877261-1F04-40B7-8C6D-CF92F38D09A3&displaylang=en) to process the schema database and produce the xsd’s to support HL7 v.2.6

I’m using the standard MSH_25_GLO_DEF.xsd, modified to support a 2.6 version id, as my MSH definition.

I have a set of BizTalk assemblies, the pipelines defined against the included 2.5 schemas  accept a test 2.5 message, the pipelines using a 2.6 schema fail to parse a 2.6 message when the timestamp is present. Here’s the sample input:

Without  a timestamp:

```
MSH|^~\&|TEST|MCM|BTAHL7InterfaceEngine||||ADT^A20|000001|P|2.6
EVN|A20|19880704
NPU|A|OCC

MSH|^~\&|BTAHL7InterfaceEngine||TEST|MCM|20090902152033||ACK^A20^ACK|100000|P|2.6|||NE
MSA|AA|000001
```

With a timestamp:

```
MSH|^~\&|TEST|MCM|BTAHL7InterfaceEngine||199112311501||ADT^A20|000001|P|2.6
EVN|A20|19880704
NPU|A|OCC

MSH|^~\&|BTAHL7InterfaceEngine||TEST|MCM|20090902152032||ACK^A20^ACK|100000|P|2.6|||NE
MSA|AR|000001
ERR|MSH^1^7^102&Data type error&HL7nnnn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HL7 2.6 MSH-7's type changed from TS to DTM. How does your schema's constraint look like?